# How to access grayscale values of an image with Vimba.c API?

Tags: c, image-processing, centroid, vimba-sdk

I'm using the Vimba API for c language. I'm having trouble to access the grayscale values of the image that I'm capturing with the camera. I'm also using the VisualStudio for the first time, since it was advised by Vimba, not sure why.

I was updating the SynchronousGrab example provided by Vimba, adding a pixel analysis after capturing the image and before printing the image to a bitmap. That pixel analysis consists of finding, in a dark grayscale image, the centroid of the lighter "cloud" of pixels.

Relevant declarations:

```
VmbError_t SynchronousGrab( const char* pCameraID, const char* pFileName, int threshold )
{
VmbFrame_t          frame;                                  // The frame we capture
VmbUint32_t         j                   = 0;                //CUSTOM
VmbUint32_t         k                   = 0;                //CUSTOM
unsigned char*      CurSrc              = 0;                //CUSTOM
int                 arraysize           = 0;                //CUSTOM
float*              coordY              = 0;                //CUSTOM
float*              coordX              = 0;                //CUSTOM
float*              intensity           = 0;                //CUSTOM
float               centroid_x          = -1;               //CUSTOM
float               centroid_y          = -1;               //CUSTOM
```

And the `VmbFrame_t` `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
    //----- In -----
    void*               buffer;             // Comprises image and ancillary data
    VmbUint32_t         bufferSize;         // Size of the data buffer

    void*               context[4];         // 4 void pointers that can be employed by the user (e.g. for storing handles)

    //----- Out -----
    VmbFrameStatus_t    receiveStatus;      // Resulting status of the receive operation
    VmbFrameFlags_t     receiveFlags;       // Flags indicating which additional frame information is available

    VmbUint32_t         imageSize;          // Size of the image data inside the data buffer
    VmbUint32_t         ancillarySize;      // Size of the ancillary data inside the data buffer

    VmbPixelFormat_t    pixelFormat;        // Pixel format of the image

    VmbUint32_t         width;              // Width of an image
    VmbUint32_t         height;             // Height of an image
    VmbUint32_t         offsetX;            // Horizontal offset of an image
    VmbUint32_t         offsetY;            // Vertical offset of an image

    VmbUint64_t         frameID;            // Unique ID of this frame in this stream
    VmbUint64_t         timestamp;          // Timestamp set by the camera
} VmbFrame_t;
```

The code that I added to the example:

```
err = VmbCaptureFrameWait( cameraHandle, &frame, nTimeout );
if ( VmbErrorSuccess == err )  //Existing SynchronousGrab code
    {   

    CurSrc = (unsigned char*)frame.buffer;                                                                                   
    for (k = 0; k < frame.height; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j < frame.width; j++) {
            if (*(CurSrc+k * frame.width + j) >= threshold) {
                coordY = realloc(coordY, ++arraysize * sizeof(*coordY));
                coordX = realloc(coordX, arraysize * sizeof(*coordX));
                intensity = realloc(intensity, arraysize * sizeof(*intensity));
                coordY[arraysize - 1] = k * (*(CurSrc + k * frame.width + j));
                coordX[arraysize - 1] = j * (*(CurSrc + k * frame.width + j));
                intensity[arraysize - 1] = (*(CurSrc + k * frame.width + j));
            }
        }
    }
    if (arraysize != 0) {
        centroid_x = getSum(coordX, arraysize) / getSum(intensity, arraysize);
        centroid_y = getSum(coordY, arraysize) / getSum(intensity, arraysize);
        printf("Centroid is in (%.1f,%.1f)\n", centroid_x, centroid_y);
        free(coordX);
        free(coordY);
        free(intensity);
        arraysize = 0;
    }

    if ( VmbFrameStatusComplete == frame.receiveStatus )  //Existing SynchronousGrab code
```

And the `getSum()` `function` I created:

```
int getSum(float* head, int size) {                         //CUSTOM FUNCTION   
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum = sum + head[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

In theory, this would work. Since I had already tried the centroid algorithm with an image (with a fixed 1440:1080 size) that I loaded through `<stdlib.h>` to a `c` application that only did that.

Now, when adapting that algorithm to a bigger size image, through `frame.width` and `frame.height`, and cycling through `frame.buffer` (that I'm not sure exactly what it holds), the centroid coordinates are no longer correct. Not only they are not correct, they actually oscilate a bit (might be due to vibrations of the physical camera/table/etc).

I had an error at the beginning, because I thought the image was the same size as the ones I was trying before, so, in the `coordX` and `coordY` assigns I was using 1440 instead of `frame.width`. Well, the first time I ran the program after editing that, the `centroidY` value kept being negative (which is quite odd since what I'm assigning to `coordY` is a product of 2 positive values), but the 3 times I ran after that, it started being positive. Although, with an error of 1900 pixels or something (`centroidX` has an error of the same magnitude). Dunno if this bit information helps or further confuses the reader.

I'm guessing that `frame.buffer` doesn't point to what I think it was pointing to, i.e., a memory array of the grayscale of every pixel with length = `frame.width` * `frame.height`. But I'm not sure, and don't know how to get out of this.

Also note that I have limited access to the place where the camera setup is, so brute-force solutions of excessive memory lookups aren't that feasible. But, if it's the only way to go, I'll manage.

**EDIT:** after posting, I just noticed that the function below my code is waiting for the completion of the function above my code. I might have messed up that. I should've placed the centroid algorithm below both functions. I just placed the algorithm after the last use of `frame` as a whole. But now I'm guessing that this isn't working because I'm looking at a non-complete image in the memory.

Comment: Why are you accumulating a `float` value using a `int` variable? (`sum = sum + head[i];`). And aside:  `a += b` is a shortcut and equivalent to `a = a + b`

Comment: `getSum` and `sum` should be `float`, indeed. Edit: And I know the shortcut but I'm too rusty and forget that type of stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@ryyker kindly pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75521929/how-to-access-grayscale-values-of-an-image-with-vimba-c-api?noredirect=1#comment133246874_75521929), the `getSum` function and `sum` variable inside it should be `float`. That, and maybe the re-positioning of the centroid algorithm (after the status change), solved my problem. It is now working as intended.